# Estrutura de Dados/ Pilhas

Tags: c

Pessoal preciso fazer um exercício de pilhas que receba String, na qual na primeira linha eu tenho que incluir o tamanho da pilha e nas outras ir dando os comandos, exemplo :

**Entrada:**

1. 5
2. E ekrofhfdufd
3. D
4. E saksajosaksa
5. E sajpodfspfdsp
6. X

**Saida:** 
 sajpodfspfdsp saksajosaksa

Os Comandos são os seguintes :

- **E-** empilhar
- **D-** desempilhar
- **X-** printar do topo pra base
- **B-** printar base para o topo
- **T-** printar o valor do topo da lista

Eu tentei fazer algo mas ta dando vários erros de char, alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como prosseguir?
Segue o que eu consegui fazer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Pilha
{
    char *itens, val;
    int topo, tamanho;

};

struct Pilha criaPilha(int);
void empilha(struct Pilha *, char);
int desempilha(struct Pilha *);
int vazia(struct Pilha);
int cheia(struct Pilha);
void topoBase(struct Pilha);
void baseTopo(struct Pilha);
void exibetopo(struct Pilha);

int main()
{
    int n, val;
    char op;
    struct Pilha p;

    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    p = criaPilha(n);

    while(scanf("%c\n", &op) != EOF)
    {
        if(op == 'E')
        {
            scanf("%s\n", val);
            empilha(&p, val);
        }
        else if(op == 'D')
        {
            desempilha(&p);
        }
        else if(op == 'X')
        {
            topoBase(p);
        }
        else if(op == 'B')
        {
            baseTopo(p);
        }

        else
        {
            exibetopo(p);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

struct Pilha criaPilha(int n)
{
    struct Pilha p;
    p.itens =malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    p.topo = -1;
    p.tamanho = n;
    return p;
}

void empilha(struct Pilha *p, char novo)
{
    if(!cheia(*p))
    {
        p->itens[++p->topo] = novo;
    }
}

char desempilha(struct Pilha *p)
{
    char ret;
    if(!vazia(*p))
    {
        ret = p->itens[p->topo--];
        return ret;
    }
}

char vazia(struct Pilha p)
{
    return p.topo == -1;
}

char cheia(struct Pilha p)
{
    return p.topo == p.tamanho-1;
}

void baseTopo(struct Pilha p)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=p.topo; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p.itens[i]);
    }
}

void topoBase(struct Pilha p)
{
    int i;
    for(i=p.topo; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p.itens[i]);
    }
}

void exibetopo(struct Pilha p)
{
    i = p.topo;
    printf("%s\n", p.itens[p.topo]);
}
```

Comment: Suas leituras não estão de acordo com o que você afirmou que são as entradas. O comando é seguido de um caractere ' ' ou de um '\n' e depois uma string?

Answer (score 1):

Tem alguns pontos a corrigir no código:

- Você declara na sua struct um `char* itens` e um `char val`. `val` nunca é usado, e `itens` é um **ponteiro de char**, ou seja, uma string. Não parece o seu objetivo. Acho que o que você quer aí é um `char** itens`, ou seja, um **ponteiro de ponteiros de char** (ou um ponteiro de strings).
- Os tipos `int` e `char` são coisas diferentes em C, você não pode declarar uma função `int desempilha(...)` e depois implementar como `char desempilha(...)`.
- O tipo `char` não é uma string. `char` é um nome péssimo aliás, entenda como `byte`. Eu vi ali que você usa `char` algumas vezes tentando se referir a strings (o método `desempilha`, por exemplo, e o `char ret` ali). Sempre que quiser strings (ou seja, sequências de bytes), use `char*` ou um array de `char` (Ex.: `char str[256];`).
- Menos relevante, mas sua instrução "`E`" não vai poder ser escrita do jeito que você quer. Como você lê um char e um `\n` para a instrução, vai ter que escrever assim:

```
5
D
E
ekrofhfdufd
E
saksajosaksa
[...]
```

---

**TL;DR**: os erros de compilação são na maioria porque você usou `int` onde devia ter usar `char` ou vice versa. Fora isso, você precisa arrumar a lógica para usar `char*` nas strings ao invés de só `char`.